# Globalization between MasterPage and Content Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, globalization

I have a master page and a few content page with their own control. Inside the master page I have a dropdown list that contain the language the user can choose. So when the user clicks on it the website content language will change accordingly.

My problem is that I can successfully change my website content by using UIculture and culture in the master page when I select other language, but I have no idea how do i change the culture from the content page since the control (dropdownlist) that determine the culture is from the master page. When I debug it seems that the content page Page_Load will run first follow by the few coding in the master page to change the language inside there.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. In the Master Page, create a public string property that returns the culture name (e.g ChosenCulture).
2. In the content page, add a MasterType directive `<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/YourMasterPage.master" %>` Then you'll be able to access MasterPage properties via `Master.` inside the Content Page
3. In the content page overrides InitializeCulture method and set UICulture property.

   ```
   protected override void InitializeCulture()
   {
       UICulture = Master.ChosenCulture;
       Culture = Master.ChosenCulture;
       base.InitializeCulture();
   }
   ```

To maintain the value of ChosenCulture between posts you can use Session:

MasterPage:

```
public string ChosenCulture
{
    get { return Session["ChosenCulture"]; }
    set { Session["ChosenCulture"] = value; }
}
```

In the DropDownList's OnChanged event, just set ChosenCulture property:

```
ChosenCulture = MyDropDownList.Value;
```

Comment: Hi i try using ur code but then the control in my content page that is link to the master page will be gone any idea ?

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand what you mean... the trick to change the culture of the content page is overriding the InitializeCultureMethod